# Cascading WMS in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

Is it possible to load external wms services into ArcMap and publish them in ArcGIS Server?

I have tried this and get the error that the layer type is not supported.

Comment: cascading WMS services are not possible, since the MSD does not support WMS services. See this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Supported_functionality_in_map_services/00sq00000083000000/

Answer (score 2):

The Esri [FAQ: Should I cascade or embed one service within another?](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35903) may be worth a read:

> Generally, cascading map services is not recommended and could
>   introduce unforeseen problems into both ArcGIS Server and ArcIMS
>   environments.
>
> A cascading service is the notion of a published map service being
>   added to a map document (MXD) and re-published as a map service.
>
> With the 9.3 release, it is not possible to re-publish a password
>   protected map service through ArcGIS Server (even as the owner of the
>   original service).
>
> Some of the known issues with cascading services include: ...